# CJK Font for embedded system

Tags: fonts, embedded, subset, cjk

For a multi-lingual application on an embedded device I need a CJK font (or one korean and one chinese font) that do not exceed 1mb. I found this to be an almost impossible task, as [Chinese fonts have around 5mb](https://medium.com/@Hynuza/typographic-design-in-asian-language-4bb1035ebb7#:%7E:text=A%20typical%20Chinese%20font%20file,not%20only%20regular%20and%20bold.) and [Korean fonts around 4mb](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/04/google-fonts-launches-korean-support.html#:%7E:text=A%20typical%20full%20Korean%20font,Latin%20fonts%20rarely%20exceed%20250Kb.).

I have already looked into font subsetting, which proves to be hard in my case, as I need to translate the whole application with about 3500 (english) words and there is no way to manually pick the chinese/korean characters I actually need. Also, no subsetting tool I looked into supported CJK languages.

I now am thinking that there must be other people out there who are dealing with the same problem. Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: It's very unlikely you'll find a CJK font under 1MB. I'd suggest you start with a font like Source Han Sans (https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-sans/) and subset---and that means you'll need to determine ahead of time a character repertoire to be supported.

Comment: Needs more detail about your platform,/application.  Do you need scalable fonts, or bitmap.  What font format can your system use -TTF, ITF, EOT, WOFF, SVG, other, proprietary?  What resources are available on the platform? What OS, what graphics/GUI library? Even what is the resolution of the display? The solution where I have had this issue is to think about it in advance and use a GUI library that supports multi-lingual interfaces.  At the high end Qt embedded, mid-range Segger emWin, and low end RamTex.  Certainly RamTex includes a tool to generate glyph subsets from the translation files.

Comment: .... https://www.ramtex.dk/iconedit/iconedit.htm takes Windows TTF fonts and generates bit-map glyphs as C code data arrays. It can generate a glyph set from Unicode translation text - generating only the glyphs necessary to render the provided text.  It's crude, you need a separate Glyph set for every font size you want, but you don't need complex font rendering and scaling code - it is pre-processed and embedded.  It can be used independently of the RamTex GUI library.

Comment: ... An example of the C code generated: https://www.ramtex.dk/iconedit/fonts-as-c-source-code.htm - size depends on font size and ant-aliasing levels.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in this project :
https://poppyworks.itch.io/silver

It's for pixel arts games though, this ttf only takes around 3MB for CJKs.

Answer (score 0):

> I now am thinking that there must be other people out there who are dealing with the same problem. Is there a solution for this problem?

These might be writing software with Chinese or Korean documentation, so searching in these language could yield more results.

- A possible take on this would be using **smaller bitmap fonts** like [Unifont](https://unifoundry.com/unifont/), and **upscale them x2** using a method such as [this one](https://hackaday.com/2020/10/25/smoothing-big-fonts-on-graphic-lcds/) to upscale it.
- Another take would be to **compress bitmap fonts block by block**, using something like GZIP (high compression) or LZ4 (fast decompression), and **have an index**. When needing some character, lookup which block it is in from the index, decompress that (small) block in RAM, and get the character data from it.
- An alternative is to considering displays as a **canvas of bits** instead of a grid of text: instead of transferring text message to the embedded system, a more capable system would **render the text and transfer the compressed bitmap** for the whole display. A bit like a low-end VNC.